# I'm trying to add two Highchart elements - 1 gauge series and 1 live weather dashboard but the CSS properties of one overwrites the other

Tags: html, css, highcharts, dashboard, gauge

I'm using Highcharts to make an AQI webpage, having a guage series to show AQI and have a weather dashboard beneath it.

The problem is the CSS properties of both clash with each other making the other not render the way it's expected to.

You can find the code here: [JS Fiddle Code](jsfiddle.net/18_dhruv/kurqpx2m/2/)

Want help to fix the properties in CSS so that everything comes up nicely on the webpage.

I tried making class and ID selectors but nothing seemed to work

Comment: This demo is a bit confusing. You first create a Gauge chart and then try to create a dashboard with a map under it. Since you are already using Dashboards, wouldn't it be better to include a gauge chart in them as well?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer. In particular, illustrate (with screenshots, mockups or sketches) your desired result and your actual result. You might expect a particular result, but people answering your question don't necessarily know what to expect. It's okay to link to jsFiddle, but we also ask that you include the relevant code in your question, because the link may break in the future.